# Visual Studio C++ bitfield struct size problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

I have created and compiled following code in GCC using packed attribute and it worked like as expected. But in Visual Studio results are not same as GCC.

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t TargetID: 6;
    enum_OPCode OPCode: 3;
    uint8_t CRC7: 7;
} struct_commDataPack_request;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

As you can see size of all elements must be 16bits = 2Bytes which is true in GCC, but in Visual Studio it returns 3Bytes! and if I decrease size of it to 15bits it will return 2Bytes.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I'm daily working on VS. Concerning bit fields, I once realized that bit fields are not packed together when base types differ. I.e. `struct Pack { unsigned a: 3; bool b: 1; };` required 2 bytes instead of 1 as intended. This might be the issue here also. Unfortunately, I cannot say what the standard is about this.

Comment: You write _"if I decrease size of it to 15bits it will return 2Bytes"_: How do you decrease it? Please [edit]  your question and add the corresponding code. Also show us what exactly `enum_OPCode` is.

Comment: Which version of VS do you use? With your example (and an `enum enum_OPCode { OPCode1, OPCode2, OPCode3, OPCode4, OPCode5, OPCode6, NOPCodes };`) I get 6 bytes in VS2013 (tried Debug and Release ). Replacing, `enum_OPCode` with `uint8_t`, I still get 3.

Comment: Don't use bit fields or packing. Bit fields are too implementation dependent and packing are just non-standard. In this case, implement the storage as a single uint16_t, and write getters and setters for each field implemented with bit shifts and masks.

Comment: I think the OPCode:3 is not distributed between different uint8_ts. Try uint16_t instead of uint8_t! (Information from cppreference.com: "For example, on some platforms, bit fields don't straddle bytes, on others they do ")

Comment: enum_OPCode type is uint8_t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, packing is just too platform dependent to really rely on it.

In VS, when you do "pack(push, 1)", you essentially set the padding to 8 bits and, as you saw, end up with three bytes (6 bits of which are padding).

Padding on GCC however (in case you did it with __attribute__((packed)) or some alias for it) can be turned off completely. That's why you see just 2 bytes.

To keep it portable, why don't you just write your own small serialization routine? Something like this:

```
struct_commDataPack_request s;
short wire = s.TargetID | (s.OPCode<<6) | (s.CRC7 << 9);
```

Comment: This does exactly match what I just observed in VS2013.

Comment: Yeah, small typo :) Well, in VS you get 5 extra bits of padding in OPCode and 1 extra bit at the end of CRC7. I have played around with it, and It seems that 8 bit is the minimum possible padding!

Answer (score 3):

I used this code to reproduce in VS2017:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef enum { A,B,C } enum_OPCode;

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t TargetID : 6;
  uint8_t OPCode : 3;
  uint8_t CRC7 : 7;
} struct_commDataPack_request;
#pragma pack(pop)

int main()
{
  printf("%zd\n", sizeof(struct_commDataPack_request));
}
```

The size here is 3.

But when I change

```
uint8_t OPCode : 3;
uint8_t CRC7 : 7;
```

to

```
uint8_t OPCode : 2;
uint8_t CRC7 : 8;
```

(overall size remains 16 bits), the size is 2.

As suggested before, best is to write your own serialisation/deserialisation.

Comment: I think Visual Studio does not distribute OPCode : 3 to two different uint8_t. Thats why OPCode : 2 reduces the size because now the OPCode fits into the uint8_t holding the TargetID.

Comment: @AndreasH. that makes sense.

Comment: Found a text on cppreference.com: "[...] on some platforms, bit fields don't straddle bytes, on others they do". So using an uint16_t should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [MS document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe.aspx#Anchor_2):

> The underlying type of a bit field must be an integral type.
>   If a bit field would overflow the boundary of the declared type (in your case is uint8_t), new units of storage are allocated.

A way to solve the problem is to use a declared type with a bigger boundary (uint16_t).

Here is the code I used:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef enum { A, B, C } enum_OPCode;

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t TargetID : 6;
    uint16_t OPCode : 3;
    uint16_t CRC7 : 7;
} struct_commDataPack_request;
#pragma pack(pop)

int main()
{
    struct_commDataPack_request packet;

    packet.TargetID = 0;
    packet.OPCode = 7;
    packet.CRC7 = 0;

    unsigned char * pData = (unsigned char *)&packet;

    printf("Packet size : %zd\n", sizeof(struct_commDataPack_request));
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(packet); i++) {
        printf("byte %d is [%02X]\n", i, pData[i] );
    }
}
```

The results :

```
Packet size : 2
byte 0 is [C0]
byte 1 is [01]
```

( 0x01C0 in bits : 0000 0001 1100 0000)